# C and V keys not working..Help!

Tags: gnome, command-line, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I was tinkering around learning the commands and stuff in terminal. I was a bit irritated that I couldn't copy and paste using only the keyboard. So I googled on how to add these shortcuts to my terminal.. I came upon [these commands on DistroGeeks](http://www.distrogeeks.com/adding-keyboard-shortcuts-ubuntu-terminal/):

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/copy -t str 'c'
```

for adding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy... and

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/paste 'v'
```

to paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>...

I ran these lines of code on my terminal and  the <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd> no longer gives the input... Uppercase works well...

Now typing <kbd>c</kbd> causes copy and simply typing <kbd>v</kbd> causes paste!

Can I undo these actions?

Comment: Just noting this out here, but the default way to copy/paste in a terminal is Ctrl+Shift+C / Ctrl+Shift+V respectively. Ctrl+C is used to abort running commands in the terminal. If you replace it with copy, I **highly recommend** you set the abort functionality to a new shortcut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal` will unset all settings you added to the gnome-terminal.

You can also unset only one key with the `--unset` option.

You might need to log off and back on for the settings to take effect.